# POST Server side form validation

Tags: php

Having some issues telling exactly where I am making an error from the php script below. It gets data via post from a HTML form. Then am trying some validations before inserting them into a database. Anyone spot anything?

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['submit_form'] ) )
{

validate_data($data)
{
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = strip_tags($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($data);
 return $data;
}
 $address = validate_data($_POST['name']);
  $address = validate_data($_POST['address']);
  $zipcode = validate_data($_POST['zipcode']);
  $county = validate_data($_POST['county']);
  $phone = validate_data($_POST['phone']);
  $email = validate_data($_POST['email']);
  $password = validate_data($_POST['password']);
  $pwVerified = validate_data($_POST['pwVerified']);

 //create connection

 // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO company (name, address, zipcode, county, phone, email, password, pwVerified )
VALUES 
                ( '$name', '$address', '$zipcode','$county','$phone', '$email', '$password', '$pwVerified')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

   // echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

}else 
 { echo "there is a problem";}
include 'sign.php';

?>
```

Comment: yeah this `$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($data);` and no idea if your POST arrays contain values or not. That function requires a db connection passed to it. `$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data);` (for one thing).

Comment: `validate_data($data) ` supposed to be a function : `function validate_data($data)`

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: see the first two comments. Plus, I wouldn't use that at all if I were you. Use a prepared statement and do away with all that.

Comment: While you can define functions inside an IF it is a lot more logical at least in this case to NOT do that. and it requires the `function` keyword in front of it as well

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared statement and parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You test the result of creating a database connection **but you dont actually make a database connection**

Comment: Apparently I solved this by comment number 2. Thank you

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You did say ___Anyone spot anything?___ Should we stop now then or do you want all the ___Anythings___ Or should we just close this as a TYPO

Comment: @BobMwenda and you think that this is going to work? `$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($data);`

Comment: It looks as though you are storing passwords in the database in plain text.  Which isn't advisable.

Comment: What does `pwVerified` stand for?

Answer (score -1):

Should be  **function**  validate_data($data). Comment 1 and 2. Thank you.

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['submit_form'] ) )
{

function validate_data($data)
{
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = strip_tags($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data);
 return $data; //the rest
```

Comment: `$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($data);` that will never work, believe me when I say this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- why not?

Comment: @Progrock Do I really have to tell you? If I do, then you don't know how that works.

Comment: Funny because it worked for me. Or else how should it be? Kindly?

Comment: @BobMwenda I find that rather hard to believe.

Comment: @BobMwenda the most funny thing is , you posted an question and then you picked an answer from comment and posted it as answer and saying it should be a function.

Comment: Read the manual on that function http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php - Procedural `string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )` and you have one parameter.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that's a better and less pompous comment.

Comment: @BobMwenda I noticed you modified your answer to contain the db connection to the escape function, thank you. However you know that you can do away with all of that and just use a MySQLi_ or PDO prepared statement ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- is my method secure from SQL injections? Do I need to have some extra layer for a starter?

Comment: @BobMwenda To a certain point, yes. However and if you eventually use a (password) hashing method such as `password_hash()`, that method of yours may do more harm than good. A prepared statement takes care of all that and takes it into consideration.